# Tools for UI test automation for Hybrid Application based on Cordova

Tags: ui-automation, sapui5

I need automate the UI tests for an hybrid application based on cordova. So far, I only need to test in android platforms.
In this project we are using the sap.m library. 
I started automating using selendroid.However, I'm not able to click or tap in my tiles elements without crashing the application.

Because we are facing a short deadline. I would like to know if there are other tools to automate UI tests that support the elements of the SAP.M library and hybrid applications ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Appium for this, see https://github.com/appium/io.appium.gappium.sampleapp

Comment: Have you used appium to automate app developed with openu5 libs ? I found this in their documentation: "RUNNING YOUR TEST APP WITH APPIUM (ANDROID DEVICES < 4.2, AND HYBRID TESTS)

Android devices before version 4.2 (API Level 17) do not have Google’s UiAutomator framework installed. This is what Appium uses to perform the automation behaviors on the device. For earlier devices or tests of hybrid (webview-based) apps, Appium comes bundled with another automation backend called Selendroid."